# Is it possible to use picklist values on lightning progress indicator?

Tags: lightning-web-components

I have a `<lightning-record-edit-form>` and inside the form I have a `<lightning-input-field field-name="customPicklist__c" variant="label-hidden"> </lightning-input-field>` that displays a picklist of statuses. Is it possible to convert the `<lightning-input-field>` to a `<lightning-progress-indicator>`? so the status picklist, will be converted to a progress indicator

Comment: For clarity, are you wanting users to be able to select the values within the progress indicator (like they'd use the picklist) or would it simply for display like the indicator is designed for?

Comment: Ideally, users can select the values within the progress indication. @Callum MacErlich

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's possible to do that, but there's a few things that you'll need to do to get it working.

First of all you'll need to retrieve the picklist values from the field which will require an Apex class. This is well fairly straight forward, and the method you'd need would look something like this:

```
@AuraEnabled
public List<String> getPickListValues(){
    List<String> pickListValuesList= new List<String>();
    Schema.DescribeFieldResult fieldResult = ObjectApiName.FieldApiName.getDescribe();
    List<Schema.PicklistEntry> ple = fieldResult.getPicklistValues();
    for( Schema.PicklistEntry pickListVal : ple){
        pickListValuesList.add(pickListVal.getLabel());
    }     
    return pickListValuesList;
}
```

Once you've got your picklist values, you can iterate over these to create the steps that users will be able to select from. Iterating to create is documented in the developer documentation for the [Progress Indicator](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning-progress-indicator/example). In addition, you'll need to have ensure that you include an onclick event handler for each step. This means your HTML file will look something like this:

```
<template>
    <lightning-progress-indicator current-step={selectedStep} type="path" variant="base">
        <template for:each={steps} for:item="step">
            <lightning-progress-step label={step.label} value={step.value} key={step.label} onclick={handleStepSelect}></lightning-progress-step>
        </template>
    </lightning-progress-indicator>
</template>
```

With the JS File:

```
import { LightningElement, wire } from 'lwc';
import getPicklistValues from '@salesforce/apex/ProgressIndicatorCC.getPicklistValues';

export default class ProgressIndicatorPathTypeWithIteration extends LightningElement {

    selectedStep;
    steps;

    @wire (getPicklistValues)
    wiredPicklistValues ({ error, data}) {
        if (data){
            let _steps;
            data.forEach((value) => {
                _steps.push({label: value, value: value});
            });
            this.steps = _steps;

        } else if (error){
            console.error(error);
        }
    }

    handleStepSelect(event){
        this.selectedStep = event.target.value;
    }
}
```